# Hide/show section based on buttonclick

Tags: c#, blazor, visibility

I'm working with Blazor HTML and I have a `<section class="showContent">` containing a form that I only want to show to those who click the "yes" option, I want to hide the form by default. Here is my code:

```
            <h5 class="stath5"><span class="badge badge-secondary">5.</span> Business / Custom Work / Services</h5>
            <p class="forPurpose">For tax purposes</p>


            <p class="statp">Do you (or a non-member on your land) have business sales, custom work, or services of $10,000 a year or more yearly turnover?</p>


            <label class="label-yes">
                <input type="radio" class="option-input radio" name="example"/>
                Yes
            </label>

            <label>
                <input type="radio" class="option-input radio" name="example" />
                No
            </label>


            @*If yes, display the following; if no, do not @* *@






    <section class="showContent">

            <p class="statp">Please specify the amount for which you have  <span class="badge badge-danger">not</span> yet paid tax:</p>


            <EditForm Model="@businessData" style="max-width:800px;" onkeydown="javascript: DisableEnterKey();">
                <FluentValidator />


                <div class="individualForms">
                    <label class="statlabel" for="businessReselling"> Business / Reselling:</label><br />
                    <InputNumber id="businessReselling" class="input" @bind-Value="@businessData.BusinessResellingGross" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="$BZ" autofocus />
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => businessData.BusinessResellingGross" />
        </div>

                <br /><hr class="statHR" />


                <div class="individualForms">
                    <label class="statlabel" for="pavementTax"> Pavement tax:</label><br />
                    <InputNumber id="pavementTax" class="input" @bind-Value="@businessData.PavementTaxGross" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="$BZ" />
            <ValidationMessage For="() => businessData.PavementTaxGross" />
                </div>


                <br /><hr class="statHR" />

                <div class="individualForms">
                    <label class="statlabel" for="customWrkServices"> Custom Work / Services:</label><br />
                    <InputNumber id="customWrkServices" for="customWrkServices" class="input" @bind-Value="@businessData.CustomWorkServicesGross" onwheel="this.blur()" placeholder="$BZ" />
                    <ValidationMessage For="() => businessData.CustomWorkServicesGross" />
        </div>


            </EditForm>

    </section>
```

This may seem simple, but I have tried some methods listed online which have not worked for my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to introduce a bool variable and wrap your `<section>` inside it:

**razor page:**

```
<label class="label-yes">
    <input type="radio" class="option-input radio" name="example" @onchange="OnUpdated"/>
    Yes
</label>

@if (ShowSection)
{
    <section class="showContent">
        ...
    </section>
}
```

**code:**

Change `ShowSection = true` when you want to show the section and `false` when you want to hide it:

```
public bool ShowSection { get; set; }

public void OnUpdated(ChangeEventArgs e)
{
    ShowSection = ((bool)e.Value);
}
```

Comment: Ok I'm having a small issue with your reply. The section is hidden by default, but when I click "yes" it remains hidden.

Comment: Did you debug and see if `e.Value` has any value in it?

Comment: I think it may not, since that seems to be the only thing that could be wrong